# Jquery autoplay video sequence not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I have been working with this code for a couple days now and I just can't figure it out.

I was able to do an auto play video sequence using youtube api. here is my example:

http://www.reyesmotion.com/videosequence/index.html

However we need an array of video ids created dynamically so I modify it to be:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('li').on("click",function(){

        var pilename = $(this).attr('data-pile');
        var videoIDs = [];
        $("li[data-pile='"+pilename+"']").each(function(index){
            videoIDs.push($(this).attr('id'));

        var player, currentVideoId = 0;

        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
                height: '350',
                width: '425',
                events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
        }

        function onPlayerReady(event) {
            event.target.loadVideoById(videoIDs[currentVideoId]);
        }

        function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
            if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
                currentVideoId++;
                if (currentVideoId < videoIDs.length) {
                    player.loadVideoById(videoIDs[currentVideoId]);
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is this attempt: 
http://www.reyesmotion.com/videoTest/index.html

However the youtube api method never gets called.

Is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two main things are causing the code to break:

1. The videos ids are passed incorrectly; they must be each wrapped with single quotes.
2. Once the page loads, the script containing the Youtube API is loading with it with an empty var videoIDs = []; hence the player is not loaded.

To correct this issue, modify your first document as follows:

1. Add a form as illustrated.
2. add the jquery code to it.
3. Remove the function that plays the videos completely from the file, along with the code preceding it (the div id="player" and the script tag containing the youtube iframe_api).

   `<form id="lists" method="post" action="FILE-TO-CALL.php">
   <input type="hidden" id="videos" name="videos" value="" />
   <input name="play_list" id="play_list" type="submit" value="Play">
   </form>`

   ```
   $('li').on("click",function(){
       var vidid = $(this).attr('id');
       if (str == "") {
          str = "'" + vidid +"'";
       }else{
          str = str + ",'" + vidid +"'";
       }
       $("#videos").val(str); //puts the str string in the hidden field
    });
   ```

   Create the second file, save it and change the name in the action="FILE-TO-CALL.php". In the second newly created file, get the value of the str sent with the form in the hidden field:

   `$vids = $_POST['videos'];`

and put this in the body:

```
`<div id="player"></div><script src="http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>`
```

and in the script tag:

```
var videoIDs = [<?php echo $vids;?>]; //the formatted string passed from the first file
var player, currentVideoId = 0;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '350',
        width: '425',
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.loadVideoById(videoIDs[currentVideoId]);
}
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
        currentVideoId++;
        if (currentVideoId < videoIDs.length) {
            player.loadVideoById(videoIDs[currentVideoId]);
        }
    }
}
```

It works!

Comment: Here it is: http://www.reyesmotion.com/videosqnc/index.html The videos aren't playing. :/

Comment: You need to name the file "FILE-TO-CALL.php" as a better suitable name, say player.php. Secondly, the $vids = $_POST['videos']; must be wrapped inside php at the top of the php file like so: `<?php $vids = $_POST['videos'];?>` to get the passed ids from the first file. Then it will play correctly.

Comment: Check it out and view the source code at [link](http://giorgioknas.com/test/testplay.html)

Comment: what browser are you using? I visit your link and videos don't play either. I'm using chrome. Is this working on your browser: http://www.reyesmotion.com/videosqnc/index.html

Comment: I use Chrome as well and tested it with Firefox and IE and all working like a charm.

Comment: So videos are actually playing one after the other in your end just like they do in here: http://www.reyesmotion.com/videosequence/index.html

Comment: Exactly the same. Go to my link and check the source code of the two files and compare them with your code. There are many things you did not do like the instructions. Fix them or copy the whole code and see that it works.

Comment: Rob thank you so much for helping me here. It is just that I visited your link and the videos aren't playing on my end either.

Comment: Okay, we were not supposed to turn this into extended discussions in comments. I made a file for you to see code. Copy the code where it is mentioned and save them into your files. [link](http://giorgioknas.com/test/code-for-files.html)

Comment: Oh, It was working the hole time! Is just that the way you made it work I need to first click on li and then press play. Thats not exactly what I expected but it does make sense. Thank as lot and sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Clicking the list to select the videos was originally in your code. I just made it work. :-)